Synchronizing Azure AD Groups with Keycloak User Logins - Need Guidance
have set up an App Registration in Microsoft Azure and integrated it into Keycloak. Now, I would like to configure Keycloak (v. 24) to synchronize the Azure AD groups of the logged-in user.
Here is what I have done so far:
Created an Azure App Registration
Added the App Registration to Keycloak as an Identity Provider
Successfully logged in users from Azure AD to Keycloak
Set Keycloak to automatically assign a default group to all users from Azure AD (I'm assuming this is how the Azure AD groups get synced, but I might be missing something)
My goal is to synchronize the groups from Azure AD for each user logging in via this setup. However, I am not sure how to configure this properly.
Does anyone have experience with this, or could provide guidance on how to set up the group synchronization accurately?
Thanks in advance!

Please edit your question and add more details like configuration set up, images and code if any
